# How can I find out the weights available with the "SF Pro" font and use these in my XF iOS and another in the Android application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

From what I understand SF Pro is now the default font used in iOS mobile. I'm unclear as to how to use the different font weights of this font and even how to find out what is available.

Does anyone know how I can specify for example two different font resources NormalFont and BoldFont and have the app use the correct SF Pro fonts for the iOS?

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="NormalFont">
        <On Platform="iOS" ???
        <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto-Regular" />  
    </OnPlatform>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="BoldFont">
        <On Platform="iOS" ???
        <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto-Bold.ttf#Roboto-Bold" />  
    </OnPlatform>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Where have you downloaded the fonts from? Also, what have you loaded into the app?

Comment: SF Pro is the default font for iOS so there is nothing to download from what I understand.  As for the Android fonts, those were downloaded from Google Fonts and I know how to set the bold / regular etc.  I have just not found a way to set the default iOS fonts using resources and I am not sure how to set different font weights.

Comment: @Alan2 If can not setting the font for iOS in forms, also can use custom-renderer to set font for control in native method .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, we need to dug into several aspects of fonts & their mechanisms.

Let's start with how to get all weights for a specific font family. Referring to the official Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app), we can log all weights for all system fonts like this (in the iOS project):

```cs
foreach (var family in UIFont.FamilyNames)
{
    var names = UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(family);
    var namesAsString = string.Join(", ", names);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Family: {family} Font names: {namesAsString}");
}
```

You can refer to system fonts by their name. System fonts are known to start with a dot (.) - e.g. San Francisco fonts can be `.SFUIText-Bold`, `.SFUI-Regular`, etc. Due to the nature of these fonts, being system ones, it was strongly discouraged for the developers to reference them by their name. One reason was that their name could change frequently.

The problem is that as of iOS 13, we're not supposed to load system fonts by name anymore. (Technically it's been advised against for a while, but iOS 13 actually enforces it by just giving you back `Times New Roman` when you ask for a system font.)

Here' a screenshot from WWDC 2019, regarding [Font instantiation (by name)](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8035):
[image: Font Instantiation (by name)]

Having said that, you can still refer to system fonts by name. After iOS 13 got released, this immediately broke everything in Xamarin. You can see in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8035). For now, they have implemented a workaround and system fonts (starting with a dot) are still possible to use. You can specify in your xaml something like this:

```xml
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="NormalFont">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value=".SFUI-Regular" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto-Regular" />  
</OnPlatform>
```

However, I would **strongly** suggest you to restrain from using the system fonts like this.

To sum up, you have 2 *preferable* options here:

1. Simply download & import the San Francisco font. The font can be downloaded for free form Apple's website. ([link](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/)). After that, just refer to Xamarin's official docs [(Use a custom font)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#use-a-custom-font)
2. Stay with the default system font and add weight attributes in xaml (bold, italic, etc).

Personally, I would go with the first approach. That way, you will always be sure that you have the font files and no update would change the font. Going with the second approach, will always refer to the system font. This font may (and will surely) change at some point.

If we want to see what the default system font is, we can do it like so:

```cs
var systemFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(17);
Debug.WriteLine($"System: {systemFont.FamilyName}");
```

Comment: Thanks for your very informative answer.  Alan works with me and is out of the office this week.  I upvoted your answer and if he's not back in time to accept I think that bounty automatically goes to the answer with the highest points. If I have any more questions I will ask you in comments.